# Access query: TOP 1 with TOTALS is doubling up my SUM

Tags: ms-access, group-by

When I run this very simple query in MS ACCESS, from just a single table, it doubles up my SUM column.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    data.Item, 
    reference.[Proposed New Category] AS Type, 
    Sum(data.[Qty Sold]) AS [Nbr Sold]
FROM 
    data 
INNER JOIN 
    reference 
ON 
    data.Item = reference.[Item Name]
WHERE 
    data.[Month Date] = [type the 1st of the month you want - like for Aug 2013, type 8/1/2013]
GROUP BY 
    data.Item, reference.[Proposed New Category]
ORDER BY 
    Sum(data.[Qty Sold]) DESC;
```

Yes, I already saw both of these, so please don't just muss up this thread by referring to them unless it's to constructively explain why they actually are applicable.  Neither of them addressed my situation (one was a self-join and the other one was also about joins - I have no self joins).

[Cumulative totals being doubled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790548/cumulative-totals-being-doubled)
[Access 2010 doubling the sum in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228492/access-2010-doubling-the-sum-in-query)

Why is this doubling up inherent in my query, and how can I avoid it??  I Just want the top one item by sum of qty sold descending...sounds so simple.  I'd like to avoid doing a bunch of typical "access junk", like make table queries etc., is there a way around it?

Comment: Can you edit your post, adding some sample data and result you wish to see? This might help us understand what you want. As the Query might not be right/maybe not the best to use. So please could you update your post?

Comment: I agree with @PaulFrancis - you need to [edit] your question to provide a small sample of data from both tables that illustrates the issue. (Yes, your query is from two tables, not "just a single table".)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could cause this is if the join is really for a many-to-many relation not the one-to-many relation intended, in which case `INNER JOIN` will return more than an intersection of the two tables in even a weak sense of 'intersection'. The fact you are joining on a text field makes me doubly suspicious - presumably `[Item Name]` isn't the primary key of `reference`? One way to test this hypothesis would be to amend the query to force a one-to-many relation:

```
SELECT TOP 1 data.Item, r2.[Proposed New Category] AS Type, Sum(data.[Qty Sold]) AS [Nbr Sold]
FROM data
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT reference.[Item Name], FIRST(reference.[Proposed New Category]) 
    FROM reference
    GROUP BY reference.[Item Name]) r2
ON d2.item = r2.[Item Name]
WHERE (((d2.[Month Date])=[type the 1st of the month you want - like for Aug 2013, type 8/1/2013]))
GROUP BY d2.Item, r2.[Proposed New Category]
ORDER BY Sum(d2.[Qty Sold]) DESC;
```

If this comes up with the expected value, then you need to fix up `reference` to remove the duplicate entries. I'd also recommend adding a proper primary key, if there isn't one there already ('Item Name' doesn't sound particularly primary key-ish, whereas 'ItemCode' or 'ItemID' would) and making the relationship with `data` against that.